# How can I access another user's home?

Tags: linux

I'm on a network where I have the rights, but how do I do it? I've been asked to look up another user's aliases for reference.

Comment: More detail would be helpful. Are you using NFS or...?

Comment: Much more details are needed to be able to answer this question. I have no idea what you are asking here. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you just asking for the name of the startup script for the other user: `~otheruser/.bashrc` or `~otheruser/.cshrc` or whatever other *rc file they have, depending on the shell?

Comment: should be ~username no /